# Questions about Lyapunov functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find a Lyapunov function for the nonautonomous ODE $z'=g(z)$ with $z=(x,y)$ and
$$
g(x,y):=(-2x-y^4,-y-x^2). 
$$
For the sake of analyzing the stability of the rest point $z=0$, one does not need to use Lyapunov functions in this particular case since all the eigenvalues of $Dg(0)$ are negative which implies that $z=0$ is asymtotically stable.

I'm  looking for a Lyapunov function for this ODE. I've tried functions of forms like 
$$V(x,y)=ax^2+by^2,$$ $$V(x,y)=ax^2+by^4,$$ and $$V(x,y)=(ax+by+c)^2+dy^2.$$

It seems that I can never get rid of the "cross" terms. For example, let $V(x,y)=(x^2/4+y^2/2)$. Then
$$
DV(z)f(z)=-(x^2+y^2)-(x^2y+xy^4/2). 
$$

It seems that appearance the "cross terms" implies on cannot have "global asymptotic stability".

Here are my **questions**:

- Do we have global asymptotic stability for the ODE? (Can one find a Lyapunov function so that $D V f$ has no "cross terms"?)
- If global asymptotic stability does not exist, how large can an open ball $B(0,r)$ be so that the system is asymptotically stable inside the ball?

---

[Typo in the definition of $g$ edited.]
$g(x,y)=(-2x-y^4,-y-x^2)$ instead of $g(x,y)
 =(-2y-y^4,-y-x^2)$. 
Hence, 
$$
Dg(x,y)=\left(
\begin{matrix}
-2&-4y^3\\
-2x&-1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
which has all negative eigenvalue at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues at (0,0) are 1 and -2 hence the fixed point (0,0) is not stable, see phase diagram below. Thus, the question needs some heavy rewriting.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{}{}$ [image]

**Edit:** The OP modified the question. The new system is stable at $(0,0)$, the existence of another fixed point forbids global asymptotic stability of $(0,0)$.

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{}{}$ [image]

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ `streamplot[{-2x-y^4,-y-x^2},{x,-5,5},{y,-4,4}]`

But $V:(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$ is a Lyapunov function on $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. To wit, $$\partial_tV(x,y)=2xx'+2yy'=-4x^2-2y^2-2xy^4-2yx^2,$$ hence, if $|x|\leqslant1$ and $|y|\leqslant1$, then  $$\partial_tV(x,y)\leqslant-4x^2-2y^2+4|x|\cdot|y|\leqslant0.$$

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad{}{}$ [image]

$\qquad\qquad\quad$ `streamplot[{-2x-y^4,-y-x^2},{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]`

Comment: It's an attractive picture but I need some words of explanation!

Comment: I saw that, but it would improve your Answer to incorporate it here.

Comment: How can one get $4|x|\cdot|y|$ in the last estimate?

Comment: @Goku If $|x|\leqslant1$ and $|y|\leqslant1$ then $|xy^4|\leqslant|x|\cdot|y|$ and $|yx^2|\leqslant|x|\cdot|y|$